# Declare SID Windows c++

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, sid

I tried to pass to a function a SID identifier

```
myFunction(SID userSid) {}
```

My seed is "S-1-5-11", but i cannot figure how to pass the SID to the function

```
PSID sid = "S-1-5-11";
myFunction(sid);
```

> No constructor for PSID to _SID

Comment: need pass pointer to the SID - myFunction(SID* userSid)

Comment: and PSID sid = "S-1-5-11"; - this is error - sid is not a string

Comment: i get `name of type not allowed _SID SID`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`SID`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379594.aspx) is a distinct *type*. It is [an opaque data structure](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/larryosterman/2004/09/01/what-is-this-thing-called-sid/) (implemented as a C structure), not just another name for a string.

You cannot pass a string to a function that requires an `SID` formal parameter. You need to create an `SID` object and pass that.

There are a variety of API functions that allow you to create and manipulate SIDs; they are listed [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379571.aspx).

If you want to create an `SID` from a string that contains [a valid SID](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379597.aspx), you can call the [`ConvertStringSidToSid`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa376402.aspx) function. For example:

```
PSID psid;
BOOL bSucceeded = ConvertStringSidToSid(TEXT("S-1-5-11"), &psid);
assert(bSucceeded != FALSE);

// ... use the SID via the pointer

// once you are finished, free it:
LocalFree(psid);
```

Comment: After the assert when i call `myFunction(psid)` i get ` no constructor appropriate for PSID to _ SID`

Comment: @mpgn Yes, your function prototype indicates that the `SID` structure is passed by copy to the function. (I'm not sure why; you usually pass these object by pointer.) Standard C rules apply here for dealing with pointers. You would dereference the pointer and pass it to the function: `myFunction(*psid);`

Comment: I tried that to, but a also get this error `Expression must be a pointer to a complete object type`

Comment: @mpgn: You can't pass a `SID` object by value, you need to pass it by pointer instead. Change `myFunction()` to take a `PSID` (aka `SID*`) parameter: `myFunction(PSID userSid) { ... }` then you can pass the `psid` variable: `myFunction(psid);`